# I have custom code that I need to bold for output. What google sheets script can I use?

Tags: database, optimization, coding-style

I have created a customized work order submission form in Forms & Sheets that auto emails a confirmation from each submission (job request form) to create a data trail of vendor activity. Fairly integrated and totally cobbled together by a lot of reading in these forums coupled with a gazillion frustrating moments of trial & error. Novice moving towards "capable" but Im stuck on a piece of code for a triggered confirmation email with random work order generator and email confirmations and toggle based management built in. The code below that I actually need help with is for that triggered confirmation email that sends a confirmation of service, work order #, and also shows everything they originally submitted. The problem is that the code I have is providing the data exactly how and I want it and placement is great, but I need to create visual distinction between the column titles and the variable submission data. Can someone please help me add a bold code to the column titles in line 16 to help create that visual differentiation between columnar "category and submission data?

```
// This constant is written in column C for rows for which an email
// has been sent successfully.
var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";

function sendEmails2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 1000;   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 27)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[19];
    var message = row[16] + "\n\n" + "Submitted By: " + row[19] + "\n\n" + "Date Submitted: " + row[0] + "\n\n" + row[21] + "\n\n" + "IMPORTANT NOTES FROM CDS: " + row[20] + "\n\n" + "Full Show Services: " + row[3] + "\n\n" + "Event Start Date: " + row[4] + "\n\n" + "Event End Date: " + row[5] + "\n\n" + "Warehouse Locations: " + row[6] + "\n\n" + "Individual Services Requested: " + row[7] + "\n\n" + "Individual Services - Warehouse(s) & Date(s) Requested: " + row[8] + "\n\n" + "Partial Hourly Staffing Details Requested: " + row[9] + "\n\n" + "Requestors Instructions / Comments: " + row[10] + "\n\n" + "Files: " + row[11] + row[12] + "\n\n" + "Thank you for your request. We appreciate your business. CDS Special Events Team ";// Second columnn
    var emailSent = row[18];
    var subject = row[16];// Third columnvar ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) {  // Prevents sending duplicates
       MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
                   sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 19).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}
```